# tickless DateListPlot

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I am using Mathematica 12.0, and when I do a DateListPlot, I get the following minimalist output:

[image]

Is this some known problem, or did I not sacrifice to the appropriate gods?

**ADDENDUM** Carl's example in the comments has the following input form:

```
Graphics[{{}, {{{}, {}, {Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], 
      RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], AbsoluteThickness[1.6]], 
     Line[{{1.8933696*^9, 1.*^12}, {3.4712928*^9, 1.1*^12}}]}}, 
   {{Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6]]}}, {{Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], 
      RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], AbsoluteThickness[1.6]]}, {}}, 
   {{Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334], RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6]]}, {}}}, {{}, {}}}, {DisplayFunction -> Identity, 
  DisplayFunction -> Identity, DisplayFunction -> Identity, 
  AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^(-1), Axes -> {False, False}, AxesLabel -> {None, None}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {1.8933696*^9, 9.944444444444445*^11}, DisplayFunction :> Identity, 
  Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}, FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, None}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Charting`DateTicksFunction[Automatic, 
      DateTicksFormat -> {Automatic}], Charting`DateTicksFunction[Automatic, 
      DateTicksFormat -> {Automatic}, "TickLabels" -> None]}}, GridLines -> {None, None}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]], 
  Method -> {"NoShowPlotTheme" -> Automatic, "OptimizePlotMarkers" -> True, 
    "CoordinatesToolOptions" -> {"DisplayFunction" -> 
       ({(Identity[#1] & )[#1[[1]]], (Identity[#1] & )[#1[[2]]]} & ), 
      "CopiedValueFunction" -> ({(Identity[#1] & )[#1[[1]]], (Identity[#1] & )[
          #1[[2]]]} & )}}, PlotRange -> {{1.8933696*^9, 3.4712928*^9}, 
    {9.944444444444445*^11, 1.1*^12}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.05]}}, 
  Ticks -> {{}, Automatic}}]
```

Comment: probably OS-related. Works as expected on Wolfram Cloud.

Comment: The OS is Windows 10, which you would think would be well-tested.

Comment: What happens if you add `FrameTicks->Automatic` to your `DateListPlot` call?

Comment: Nothing at all, it looks exactly the same.

Comment: What about `DateListPlot[TimeSeries[{{{1960}, 10^12}, {{2010}, 1.1*^12}}]]`? Also, what does the `InputForm` look like?

Comment: @kglr Exactly the same.

Comment: @CarlWoll Your example has no ticks either.  I will put the input form in the body, since even your simple example has a long input form.

Comment: You have DynamicUpdating turned off. Turn it back on!

Comment: I get ticks in Mathematica 11.3 on windows 7. Maybe change since 12?